# Oracle procedure doesn't see uncommitted data inserted in same session

Tags: transactions, oracle10g

A have a single Oracle session that inserts some data by means of a call to a stored procedure in a package.
Before committing, a simple select within the same session sees the new data.
So far so good.

If however, I try to read the data by means of a call to a stored function that returns a table of a user defined object, the newly inserted data is not there.

I repeat, everything is done within a single session and the inserts are not committed (yet).

My stored function (the one that's reading the data) needs the pragma *autonomous transaction* since it's inserting data into a table.
I have the impression that this causes my problem but I'm not sure.

Can anyone please confirm or deny this and most of all, give me a hint on how to resolve it?

**UPDATE**
The autonomous transaction within the function is necessary only if that function is inserting into another table (not the table object that the function returns).
Removing this pragma, everything works correctly.

Comment: Yes, using that pragma is causing your issues.  Why do you need to use the pragma?  You can insert without that...unless you are calling from a trigger and getting a mutating data exception.  In which case you may need to look into compound triggers.

Comment: Why is a function that returns a table also inserting data (presumably into a different table)?  If you are doing some sort of logging, you likely want to factor out the logging code from the function and declare only the logging method to be an autonomous transaction.

Comment: I figured out the autonomous transaction is not necessary. Thanks @Del and Justin Cave (I can tag only 1 person unfortunately)

Comment: @Del, there were no compound triggers in Oracle 10g. Not that it matters much here, just saying.